# High wattage speaker using low wattage amplifier

Tags: amplifier, speakers, watts

If I have [a 250W amplifier](http://www.altronics.com.au/index.asp?area=item&id=K5181) and I want to use a set of speakers:

subwoofer x 1, 4 ohms x 1
mid-rage x 1, 4 ohms x 1
tweeters x 2, 8 ohms x 2

with a combined handeling wattage that surpasses 250W. will this work?

This is for a yeah 12 electronics Major Work and I need help

Comment: How many channels does the amp have? What impedance are your speakers? What about the amp?

Comment: Not related to electronic design and need more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible but how well it works will depend on the specifics.

Power dissipation is a linear functional which means that the power across several loads does not depend on how they are configured.

So if you have 10 loads each dissipating 10W the total dissipation is 100W regardless of how they are connected. (although different typologies could result in different dissipation per load).

In your case though, the answer is more difficult because tweeters do not dissipate nearly as much power as sub-woofers. It might require a 200W subwoofer or more to "soak" up all the amplifier power. You run a real risk of burning up the speakers in your specific case.

That is, you can't expect the power to be evenly divided among your speakers.

You could simulate the circuits by using filters and resistive or even inductive loads for the speakers to get a better approximation or you could wire them up appropriately(so that the total load does not exceed the amps specs and and use a smaller amplifier(or lower volume) and measure the power dissipation in each device. Raise the power some and measure again. This will be the empirical way to make sure no speaker is using more power than it is rated.

Obviously if each speaker can handle 1000W then the answer is moot... since you did not provide the power dissipation capabilities of the speakers it is impossible to even give a rough estimate.

You say the total combined wattage is 250W but it really doesn't help in any way. 250/3 ~= 83.3 watts. Each speaker could be destroyed. If one speaker = 260W and the other's 5W each then one speaker will surely survive.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the power distribution between the various speakers, which in turn depends on the crossover functions and the spectrum analysis of the music or whatever you are playing through them. Typically music is concentrated around 100-500Hz but it depends heavily on genre, as deliberately distorted guitars for example have lots of strong harmonics. The question isn't really answerable here.